# Lost code and triggers in google spreadsheet and google-apps-script on V8 update. How to rollback?

Tags: google-apps-script

I was getting a notice for a few days that if I didn't update and if they found my code to be compatible, it will be updated to V8 runtime automatically. It happened without any notification to me. Today I open the scripts from my spreadsheet and I see a blank file. The project and associated triggers/logs disappeared from the google apps script dashboard as well.

How to get my code and triggers back?

Comment: Create a issue in issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Hello, can you share the spreadsheet link?

Comment: I believe you can still disable v8.

Answer (score 0):

Rollback:

[image]

At some point you will have to modify your script to work with the new V8 engine but for now perhaps going back to Rhino may allow you to find your code.

Comment: I did that but neither my scripts / project nor triggers came back.